# How to call a specific ViewController when an event happens?

Tags: ios, swift

just need a friendly suggestion. Say you have 3 viewcontrollers:

ViewController A
ViewController B
ViewController C

In ViewController A, you have a button and label. Label has default text 0. When you click the button it will add 1 to the label going for 1, then 2 then 3 and so on. When it reaches 10 it will modally call ViewController C. I read that you may need to use willSet or didSet, Am I getting this right? Any recommendations regarding the matter? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to just manually update the label after you update the value:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var value = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        value += 1

        updateLabel()
    }

    private func updateLabel() {
        label.text = "\(value)"

        if value >= 10 {
            let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController")
            present(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I strive to keep a clear separation between the "model" (the `value`) and the "view" (the `@IBOutlet`).

But you asked:

> I read that you may need to use `willSet` or `didSet`, Am I getting this right?

Yes, you can do that. So, instead of manually updating the label, you can have an `didSet` observer for that variable that initiates that yourself:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var value = 0 {
        didSet {
            updateLabel()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        value += 1
    }

    private func updateLabel() {
        guard let label = label else { return }

        label.text = "\(value)"

        if value >= 10 {
            let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController")
            present(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

This second, `didSet`, pattern is especially useful when the observed property might be updated by other classes.

Note, there was a subtle change I introduced in `updateLabel` method in this observer pattern. Usually, view controllers use their implicitly unwrapped optional outlets (the `!` after the type associated with the `@IBOutlet`) without checking if the outlet is hooked up, because they can be confident that if the view controller reached that part of code, the view associated with the view controller must have been loaded, too.

But in this observer pattern we don't know that. For example, the presenting view controller may have instantiated this view controller, set the `value` to something other than `0`, and then presented this view controller. In that scenario, `value` is being updated before the view associated with this view controller has been loaded. Fortunately, this is easily resolved a number of ways. In this example, I use `guard` to create a local `label` reference if `label` was not `nil`. If `label` was `nil`, else `return`.

Comment: These clarified my notion regarding when is best to use didSet or just manually coding to the next viewControler. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction buttonSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
   var value = Int(label.text)
   value += 1
   if value >= 9 {
       //present ViewController C
   }
   else {
       label.text = "\(value)"
   }
}
```

Comment: in the //present Viewcontroller C, is it ok to add something like this "if let viewControllerC = UIStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerC") as? SecondViewController { self.present(viewControllerC, animated: true, completion: nil) } here? Is this acceptable?

Comment: Sure it is accepable